# Json parsing in skyscanner pricing api

Tags: android, json, android-volley, skyscanner

I started working with sky-scanner API using volley on Android. I am able to poll the response from the API, however I have no clue how to parse the json which is sent in response, please see json below. The json response is very big, I have never worked with such responses before thus have no idea how can I handle this.

Can someone please help me figure this out? There is no sample implementation done by anyone for skyscanner for android.
JSON response to be parsed to get price, agents, flight number, carrier, duration of flight, image URL of flight.

```
 {
  "SessionKey": "97d1_ecilpojl_A",
  "Query": {
    "Country": "IN",
    "Currency": "INR",
    "Locale": "en-us",
    "Adults": 1,
    "Children": 0,
    "Infants": 0,
    "OriginPlace": "12627",
    "DestinationPlace": "11712",
    "OutboundDate": "2016-10-09",
    "LocationSchema": "Default",
    "CabinClass": "Economy",
    "GroupPricing": false
  },
  "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
  "Itineraries": [
    {
      "OutboundLegId": "12627-1610091100-AI-1-11712-1610091515",
      "PricingOptions": [
        {
          "Agents": [
            1963108
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 19391.08,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fat24%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            2176206
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 20190,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fcpin%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            4575202
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 20315,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fyatr%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            4056270
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 20457.92,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2ftpin%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            1943172
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 20876,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fakbt%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            3987150
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 20888.5,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2ft2in%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-09%2fair%2ftrava%2fflights%3fitinerary%3dflight%7c-32672%7c446%7c12627%7c2016-10-09T11%3a00%7c10957%7c2016-10-09T12%3a35%3bflight%7c-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            4035534
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 20959.41,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2ftgin%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            1964238
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 21207.92,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fatin%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            4060673
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 21782,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2ftrea%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            3911604
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 21782,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fsast%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            2391001
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 21782,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http1.prod_0148f8394d6c2b79a407121f74dce6e1%26commercial_filters%3dfalse%26q_datetime_utc%3d2016-10-02T12%3a09%3a13"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            4260937
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 22217.64,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fviai%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            3929744
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 22417.66,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http32672%26passengers%3d1%2c0%2c0%26channel%3ddataapi%26cabin_class%3deconomy%26facilitated%3dfalse%26ticket_price%3d22417.66%26is_npt%3dfalse%26is_multipart%3dfal
        }
      ],
      "BookingDetailsLink": {
        "Uri": "/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/97d115d901944a33a4084a4a3170905f_ecilpojl_A1EA190098863E15CE039BCA9C3B1D16/booking",
        "Body": "OutboundLegId=12627-1610091100-AI-1-11712-1610091515&InboundLegId=",
        "Method": "PUT"
      }
    },
    {
      "OutboundLegId": "12627-1610090820-9W,AI-1-11712-1610091515",
      "PricingOptions": [
        {
          "Agents": [
            1963108
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 37113.61,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fat24%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-09%2fair%2ftrava%2fflights%3fitinerary%3dflight%7c-32177%7c2367%7c12627%7c2016-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            2176206
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 38374,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fcpin%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-09%2fair%2ftrava%2fflights%3fitinerary%3dflight%7c-32177%7c2367%7c12627%7c2016-10-09T08%3a20%7c10957%7c2016-10-09T09%3a45%3bflight%7c-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            4056270
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 38854.31,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2ftpin%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            1964238
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 39604.31,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_cje=9CRwSnJAYX4dZyvkLfQf7nyRn0MxGbhiKjD2KHvGPF9n99euZVUDq%2bzBrzQGTfTH&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fIN%2fen-us%2fINR%2fatin%2f1%2f12627.11712.2016-10-"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            2627411
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 39932.95,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?_1.prod_8365f3bbc5ef11ab38406bb350796374%26commercial_filters%3dfalse%26q_datetime_utc%3d2016-10-02T12%3a09%3a12"
        },
        {
          "Agents": [
            2042574
          ],
          "QuoteAgeInMinutes": 5,
          "Price": 43940.34,
          "DeeplinkUrl": "/deeplink/v2?32672%26passengers%3d1%2c0%2c0%26channel%3ddataapi%26cabin_class%3deconomy%26facilitated%3dfalse%26ticket_price%3d43940.34%26is_npt%3dfalse%26is_multipart%3dfalse%26client_id%3dskyscanner_b2b%26request_id%3dd4cc5531-1a4b-4c76-a063-447e7a8baeea%26deeplink_ids%3dap-northeast-1.prod_0b228b45aaf97f3276f40ee4109e8faf%26commercial_filters%3dfalse%26q_datetime_utc%3d2016-10-02T12%3a09%3a13"
        }
      ],
      "BookingDetailsLink": {
        "Uri": "/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/97d115d901944a33a4084a4a3170905f_ecilpojl_A1EA190098863E15CE039BCA9C3B1D16/booking",
        "Body": "OutboundLegId=12627-1610090820-9W,AI-1-11712-1610091515&InboundLegId=",
        "Method": "PUT"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Legs": [
    {
      "Id": "12627-1610091100-AI-1-11712-1610091515",
      "SegmentIds": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "OriginStation": 12627,
      "DestinationStation": 11712,
      "Departure": "2016-10-09T11:00:00",
      "Arrival": "2016-10-09T15:15:00",
      "Duration": 255,
      "JourneyMode": "Flight",
      "Stops": [
        10957
      ],
      "Carriers": [
        841
      ],
      "OperatingCarriers": [
        841
      ],
      "Directionality": "Outbound",
      "FlightNumbers": [
        {
          "FlightNumber": "446",
          "CarrierId": 841
        },
        {
          "FlightNumber": "433",
          "CarrierId": 841
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "12627-1610090820-9W,AI-1-11712-1610091515",
      "SegmentIds": [
        3,
        2
      ],
      "OriginStation": 12627,
      "DestinationStation": 11712,
      "Departure": "2016-10-09T08:20:00",
      "Arrival": "2016-10-09T15:15:00",
      "Duration": 415,
      "JourneyMode": "Flight",
      "Stops": [
        10957
      ],
      "Carriers": [
        471,
        841
      ],
      "OperatingCarriers": [
        471,
        841
      ],
      "Directionality": "Outbound",
      "FlightNumbers": [
        {
          "FlightNumber": "433",
          "CarrierId": 841
        },
        {
          "FlightNumber": "2367",
          "CarrierId": 471
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Segments": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "OriginStation": 12627,
      "DestinationStation": 10957,
      "DepartureDateTime": "2016-10-09T11:00:00",
      "ArrivalDateTime": "2016-10-09T12:35:00",
      "Carrier": 841,
      "OperatingCarrier": 841,
      "Duration": 95,
      "FlightNumber": "446",
      "JourneyMode": "Flight",
      "Directionality": "Outbound"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "OriginStation": 10957,
      "DestinationStation": 11712,
      "DepartureDateTime": "2016-10-09T13:40:00",
      "ArrivalDateTime": "2016-10-09T15:15:00",
      "Carrier": 841,
      "OperatingCarrier": 841,
      "Duration": 95,
      "FlightNumber": "433",
      "JourneyMode": "Flight",
      "Directionality": "Outbound"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "OriginStation": 12627,
      "DestinationStation": 10957,
      "DepartureDateTime": "2016-10-09T08:20:00",
      "ArrivalDateTime": "2016-10-09T09:45:00",
      "Carrier": 471,
      "OperatingCarrier": 471,
      "Duration": 85,
      "FlightNumber": "2367",
      "JourneyMode": "Flight",
      "Directionality": "Outbound"
    }
  ],
  "Carriers": [
    {
      "Id": 841,
      "Code": "AI",
      "Name": "Air India",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/airlines/AI.png",
      "DisplayCode": "AI"
    },
    {
      "Id": 471,
      "Code": "9W",
      "Name": "Jet Airways",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/airlines/9W.png",
      "DisplayCode": "9W"
    }
  ],
  "Agents": [
    {
      "Id": 1963108,
      "Name": "Mytrip",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/at24.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "BookingNumber": "+448447747881",
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2176206,
      "Name": "Cheapticket.in",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/cpin.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4575202,
      "Name": "Yatra.com",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/yatr.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "BookingNumber": "18001029900",
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4056270,
      "Name": "Tripsta",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/tpin.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1943172,
      "Name": "AkbarTravels.com",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/akbt.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3987150,
      "Name": "Travel2be",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/t2in.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4035534,
      "Name": "Travelgenio",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/tgin.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1964238,
      "Name": "airtickets",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/atin.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4060673,
      "Name": "Traveasy.co.in",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/trea.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3911604,
      "Name": "Sastiticket.com",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/sast.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2391001,
      "Name": "EaseMyTrip.com",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/emti.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4260937,
      "Name": "via.com",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/viai.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3929744,
      "Name": "Simplio",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/simp.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2627411,
      "Name": "GotoGate",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/gtas.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2042574,
      "Name": "Bravofly",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/bfin.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1882712,
      "Name": "ebookers",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/a178.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": true,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4366985,
      "Name": "Wegoby.com",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/wgby.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3291237,
      "Name": "My Travel Genie",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/mtge.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3588558,
      "Name": "Tripair",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/pein.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "Type": "TravelAgent"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2834897,
      "Name": "Air India",
      "ImageUrl": "http://s1.apideeplink.com/images/websites/inda.png",
      "Status": "UpdatesComplete",
      "OptimisedForMobile": false,
      "BookingNumber": "18001801407",
      "Type": "Airline"
    }
  ],
  "Places": [
    {
      "Id": 12627,
      "ParentId": 3462,
      "Code": "IXL",
      "Type": "Airport",
      "Name": "Leh"
    },
    {
      "Id": 10957,
      "ParentId": 3401,
      "Code": "DEL",
      "Type": "Airport",
      "Name": "New Delhi"
    },
    {
      "Id": 11712,
      "ParentId": 3424,
      "Code": "GAY",
      "Type": "Airport",
      "Name": "Gaya"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3462,
      "ParentId": 170,
      "Code": "IXL",
      "Type": "City",
      "Name": "Leh"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3401,
      "ParentId": 170,
      "Code": "DEL",
      "Type": "City",
      "Name": "New Delhi"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3424,
      "ParentId": 170,
      "Code": "GAY",
      "Type": "City",
      "Name": "Gaya"
    },
    {
      "Id": 170,
      "Code": "IN",
      "Type": "Country",
      "Name": "India"
    }
  ],
  "Currencies": [
    {
      "Code": "INR",
      "Symbol": "₹",
      "ThousandsSeparator": ",",
      "DecimalSeparator": ".",
      "SymbolOnLeft": true,
      "SpaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol": false,
      "RoundingCoefficient": 0,
      "DecimalDigits": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the json response then? And any other relevant code. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i pasted the json response here [link](http://pastebin.com/SMw1TTu6 ) , the pojo classes I was able to create from the json response above is this : [link](http://pastebin.com/080AvUd3). Basically I want to display the cheapest to costliest flights in a recycler view(each row would show the flight name, price, duration of flight,flight logo), for that i need to push the data from response into the arraylist, for that response has to be parsed, i need help with parsing the response.

Comment: Please paste it in the question rather than linking though. Just edit the question.

Comment: it is very large thats why i gave a link to it.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java#18998203

Comment: which values you need from JSON responce ??

Comment: @ghap you need to paste the JSON here, Not able to see the JSON in Pakistan.

Comment: i have added the json, pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to pull the json data then try using this js script:

1. Make sure to add jQuery
2. Change the value of the **url** variable with the session poll url you created

NOTE: Please take note that you will encounter cross origin error when you try to run this script here.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

( function( window, document, $ ){

    var app = {};


    app.init = function()
    {
       app.flightsGeo();
    };
    
    app.flightsGeo = function( )
    {     
        // the session poll url you created
        var url = 'http://business.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/hk1/v1.0/<sessionKey>?apikey=<apikey>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( response ){
                var itineraries = response.Itineraries;
                var agents      = response.Agents;
                var legs        = response.Legs;
                var carriers    = response.Carriers;
                var places      = response.Places;

                $.each(itineraries, function( itineraryKey, itineraryVal ){
                    var inbound          = app.getObjects( legs, 'Id', itineraryVal.InboundLegId),
                        inDepartureTime = inbound[0].Departure,
                        inArrivalTime   = inbound[0].Arrival,
                        inDepartureDate = inbound[0].Departure,
                        inArrivalDate   = inbound[0].Arrival,
                        inOrigin        = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', inbound[0].DestinationStation),
                        inDestination   = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', inbound[0].OriginStation),
                        inCarriers      = app.getObjects( carriers, 'Id', inbound[0].OperatingCarriers[0]);

                    var outbound         = app.getObjects( legs, 'Id', itineraryVal.OutboundLegId),
                        outDepartureTime = outbound[0].Departure,
                        outArrivalTime   = outbound[0].Arrival,
                        outDepartureDate = outbound[0].Departure,
                        outArrivalDate   = outbound[0].Arrival,
                        outOrigin        = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', outbound[0].DestinationStation),
                        outDestination   = app.getObjects( places, 'Id', outbound[0].OriginStation),
                        outCarriers      = app.getObjects( carriers, 'Id', outbound[0].OperatingCarriers[0]);


                    var agent     = app.getObjects( agents, 'Id', itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].Agents[0]);
                    var price     = itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].Price.toFixed(2);
                    var permalink = itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].DeeplinkUrl;
                    var time      = itineraryVal.PricingOptions[0].QuoteAgeInMinutes;

     // NEW FORMAT OF DATA
                    var data = {
                        agent     : agent,
                        price     : price,
                        time      : time,
                        permalink : permalink,
                        inbound    : {
                            time : {
                                departure : inDepartureTime,
                                arrival   : inArrivalTime
                            },
                            date : {
                                departure : inDepartureDate,
                                arrival   : inArrivalDate
                            },
                            station : {
                                origin      : inOrigin,
                                destination : inDestination
                            },
                            carriers : inCarriers
                        },
                        outbound  : {
                            time : {
                                departure : outDepartureTime,
                                arrival   : outArrivalTime
                            },
                            date : {
                                departure : outDepartureDate,
                                arrival   : outArrivalDate
                            },
                            station : {
                                origin      : outOrigin,
                                destination : outDestination
                            },
                            carriers : outCarriers
                        }
                    };
     
                    // will display the NEW FORMAT OF DATA
     console.log( data );
                });
            },
            error: function( error ){
                console.log( error );
            }
        });
    };

 app.displayData = function( data  )
 {
  console.log( data );
 };

    app.getObjects = function(obj, key, val) {
        var objects = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
            if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                objects = objects.concat(app.getObjects(obj[i], key, val));    
            } else 
            //if key matches and value matches or if key matches and value is not passed (eliminating the case where key matches but passed value does not)
            if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
                objects.push(obj);
            } else if (obj[i] == val && key == ''){
                //only add if the object is not already in the array
                if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
                    objects.push(obj);
                }
            }
        }
        return objects;
    };


    $(document).ready( app.init );

    return app;

})( window, document, jQuery );

</script>
```

P.S. I hope this will helps you the idea how to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show a basic example of how to parse. Take the following sample JSON.
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

How to get the contacts list.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("Your JSON String here");
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.optJSONArray("contacts");
```

How to calculate the phone number

```
//Get first contact


   JSONObject firstContact = contacts.optJSONObject(0);
   JSONObject phone = firstContact.optJSONObject("phone");
   String mobileNo = phone.optString("mobile");
```

Similarly you can apply this technique to your JSON.